# Appium error using real android device

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting  error in the appium. It is working fine in the emulator but not in the device. Please refer the code and error log below. Could anyone let me know the reason for the error.

```
//Code///////////////////////////////////////
public void setUp() throws Exception{
File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/app");
File app = new File(appDir, "app.apk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "SCH-I535");

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.app");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.justwink.homepage.HomePageActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity",          "com.app.homepage.HomePageActivity");


try {
    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);       
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: **tl;dr:** *Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: com.justwink/.homepage.HomePageActivity never started. Current: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing  the appActivity name.
Orginally I used hierarchy viewer to find the activity name.
When I used the command
aapt dump badging sample.apk it showed the original activity name.

Answer (score 1):

You may first need to ignore the below code first

```
*File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/app");
File app = new File(appDir, "justwink-usa-2.3.2.218221.69.apk");*
```

match your setup code with this one

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","sony xperia Z");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
   driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: I had an issue with the launch activity name. It worked fine once I changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way you can get the current activity by running following adb command

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
```